# PHP - same path, but require gets different file (localhost vs server)

Tags: php

I am currently working on a poorly written legacy web project yet still trying to understand certain weird things about it.
Let's say I have the following file structure

```
- htdocs/
-- index.php
-- vendor/
--- autoload.php
-- src/
--- news2.php
--- vendor/
---- autoload.php
```

The `htdocs/index.php` file includes `htdocs/src/news2.php` file.
And the `htdocs/src/news2.php` includes the line

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

The local XAMPP copy works as expected and includes `htdocs/src/vendor/autoload.php`
However, the server version behaves differently and includes `htdocs/vendor/autoload.php` instead.
Is that normal behaviour and what could be the reason?
I checked if there are any symlinks and there are none. Otherwise, I am clueless.
PHP is 5.6, the server has more or less regular Ubuntu LAMP.

Comment: you can try to check the current working dir of php `echo getcwd()`

Comment: Are both `autoload.php` files the same or largely similar? One wildly speculative guess is that the original developer duplicated these, probably unnecessarily. I wonder if it's a composer autoload (I'm guessing not) or something home-rolled.

Comment: It might be worth showing us the contents of autoload.php, as that might provide some helpful context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP include path are resolved based on the `include_path` value in the php.ini configuration file.

`include_path` value is a list of directories separated by `:`

The default value of `include_path` is something like `".:/usr/share/php"`

In this case PHP will look first in the current working dir (`.`) then in `/usr/share/php`.

If the file you want to include is not found in any of this directories it will look in the directory of the script where the `require` resides.

Probably you don't have the dot in front of the `include_path` setting in your local php.ini and the include path is always resolved relatively to the script directory.

You can remove the dot in the `include_path` setting on your server or change the line in `news2.php` to `require __DIR__ . /vendor/autoload.php`

You can also use `get_include_path` to check your current configuration and `set_include_path` function to change the `include_path` setting programmatically without edit the php.ini

From the PHP Manual:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.get-include-path.php

---

**Edit based on comments:**

Under XAMPP for Windows the default value for `include_path` is `C:\path_to_xampp\php\PEAR` to keep consistency with Linux's default you need to add `.`

Under Windows you have to use semicolon (`;`) instead of colon (`:`) for separating multiple paths. Anyhow, if multiple path are used, you must surround everything in quotes:

```
include_path= ".;C:path_to_xampp\php\PEAR"
```

If this still doesn't fix the issue keep in mind that Apache's configuration can overwrite any setting with `php_value`.

You can look for `php_value` occurrences in `httpd.conf` and `.htaccess`

From the PHP Manual:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Comment: Totally correct! My server path is `.:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php5/PEAR`
While my local one is simply `\xampp\php\PEAR`
Thank you very much for that! It's the first time I came across this issue and I never had to understand `include_path` setting.

Comment: However, when I try to change my local XAMPP `include_path` to `.:\xampp\php\PEAR` it still includes files in `htdocs/src` directory for some reason...

Comment: Have you restarted apache service?

Comment: Of course. So I set `include_path = .;\xampp\php\PEAR`, restarted apache
`get_include_path` outputs `.`, but the included files still gives `C:\source\htdocs\src\vendor\autoload.php`

Comment: Just worth mentioning that I am trying to sync localhost with the server, not the other way round (just re-read my initital post which might state the opposite).

Comment: Just tested with XAMPP 5.6.40 and it worked as described. I can confirm that under Windows the default include_path is missing the dot. Watch out that on Windows you have to use semicolon instead of colon. My current setting is include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR". Keep in mind that php.ini settings can be overridden by Apache's configuration with php_value, if still doesn't work you can check there.